# Is there a way to send a reminder email to a user if they forget to submit a record for approval?

Tags: approval-process, email-alert

I have an approval process in place where the submitter needs to select the approver so I cannot automatically submit the record for approval.  Is there a way to send an email alert to the creator of the record reminding them to submit the request for approval?

Comment: Yes, you could do this in a Process Builder or Workflow Rule. Where are you stuck in this process?

Comment: What criteria would be set in the process builder flow?  How do you see if a record has been submitted for approval?

Comment: You can't directly see if it's in approval (if I recall correctly), but you can use a Field Update when the record is submitted to identify that a record has entered a specific approval process (e.g. by changing the status).

Comment: I did this (created a checkbox, submitted for approval) and I check that box upon submission and then created a workflow to trigger after an hour if that box is unchecked, but the WF rule is triggering whether the box is checked or not.